# prove the sequence is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Im asked to show the sequence $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{3+2a_{n}}$ where $a_{1}=0, a_{2}=1$ is increasing and bounded and therefore convergent.

I don't even know how to start the proof. Im sure it increases because its essentially adding a really small number each time and the number gets very small since its being square rooted a bunch of times but i'm having a real issue showing that it actually is increasing for all n.

$$
a_{2}=\sqrt{3} \\
a_{3}=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3}} \\
a_{4}=\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3+2\sqrt{3}}}
$$

Everything I try to do leads nowhere and makes no sense. I've seen some proofs that go about by squaring both sides then solving the resulting quadratic equation assuming the sequence has a limit but im not sure how that shows that its increasing. If anyone has any tips that might push my in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a_n \ge 0$ and

$$a_{n+1}^2 - a_n^2 = 3 + 2a_n - 3 -2a_{n-1} = 2(a_n - a_{n-1})$$

thus one can argue by induction that $a_n$ is increasing.

Although you didn't ask, you can also prove by induction that $a_n \le 3$.

Comment: It's really embarrassing i'm not understanding any of this. I get that $a_{n} \ge 0$ and that  $a^2_{n+1} = 3+2a_{n}$ but im confused as how the difference between the two shows its increasing

Comment: $a_n$ is increasing if and only if $a_{n+1} \ge a_n \ge 0$ for all $n$, which is the same as $a_{n+1} - a_n$ is nonnegative for all $n$. @user3258845

Comment: Yes, I see now. Thank you. I'm really not having a good time learning this math. I spend hours looking at a problem and get no where, is there a some book I can read or some resources that might help me out?

Comment: This sequence stuff is difficult, especially if this is the first time you encounter this. Of course there are some good books around but I strongly suggest you either talk more to a human or ask more on math stackexchange. Also the more you tell us how you do not understand the problem, the easier others can help you. @user3258845

Comment: I asked a professor and he recommended I think about it harder, I'll definitely start asking for questions on stackexchange